# how to Disable views behind relative layout popup - android

Tags: android

I have a relative layout popup which shows on a button click. I have some other views on the same screen, and the popup covers them. But when I click on the popup , the controls/views behind are getting clicked. How to disable this?

( One solution I have is to get all the views and `setClickable = false`. )

But I am looking for some other solution, like to get focus on the current view so that the other views are set disabled.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem, and finally **instead** of setting everything **behind** as clickable=false, I simply added clickable=**true** to **the popup layout** and it fixed it. The clickable views behind the popup no longer respond to click events through the popup. :)  And I didn't even have to change my popup into a dialog. :)

Answer (score 3):

Activate setOnClickListener() to the RelativeLayout object.This catches all the clicks and prevents control/views behind getting clicked.

eg :-

```
    RelativeLayout rObj = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourRelativeLayout);
    rObj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // filter touches when underlying view is Obscured by this view.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For this make your `RelativeLayout` to `BringToFront()`

and make other views `SetEnabled(false)`